# Generate possible combinations by range and length

Tags: beginner, haskell, recursion, combinatorics

I am learning Haskell and I implemented a recursive function that generates possible strings by length and array (e.g. `['a'..'z']`):

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = []
comb 1 r = map (:[]) r  -- convert "abc.." to ["a","b"...]
comb n r = [i:s | i <- r, s <- comb (n-1) r]
```

For example, `comb 2 ['a'..'z']` gives `["aa","ab","ac", ... "zx","zy","zz"]`. It works with any range: `comb 3 [0,1]` is `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1] ... [1,1,0],[1,1,1]]`. Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: This function is called `replicateM` in `Control.Monad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks very good already!

I think it is nicer to have a single base-case, which is possible if you change the `comb 0 _` case:

```hs
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb n r = [i:s | i <- r, s <- comb (n-1) r]
```

This also kind of makes sense: every element of the resulting list has length `n` and there are `(length r) ^ n` such elements. Since `(length r) ^ 0 = 1`, I would expect one element of length 0 in the resulting list.

You can also use the `... <$> ... <*> ...` pattern here, then you do not have to use the useless `i` and `s` names:

```hs
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb n r = (:) <$> r <*> comb (n-1) r
```

The following is somewhat more advanced, maybe not suitable for a beginner, so don't worry if it doesn't make sense yet.

Additionally, with the simplified base case this now forms a standard recursion scheme over the natural number argument. You could express it as a fold over natural numbers:

```hs
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

foldNat :: b -> (b -> b) -> Nat -> b
foldNat z s Zero = z
foldNat z s (Succ n) = s (foldNat z s n)

comb :: [a] -> Nat -> [[a]]
comb r = foldNat [[]] (\r' -> (:) <$> r <*> r')
```

I would not recommend to actually write it this way, but I think it is good to be aware of it.

Comment: I'd probably choose `comb n = sequenceA . replicate n` instead of explicit recursion. Feel free to incorporate that into your answer if you want to :)